# What's the meaning of "to previous versions"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This Standard , which is currently designated Digital Imaging and
>   Communications in Medicine(DICOM), embodies a number of major
>   enhancements **to previous versions** of the ACR-NEMA Standard.

Does it mean "compared to previous versions "?
If so , why the word "compared" can be elided?

Answer (score 1):

The ellipsis is *made* in *(made) to previous versions.*

Thus, it means enhancements have been made to previous versions.

The Standard embodies, possesses, has, or contains those enhancements.